# Visual C++ parallel_for + vectors access violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, parallel.for

I am trying to convert a process that loops through a ~12,000x12,000 cell matrix (around 125 times) to use parallel processing (via `parallel_for`).  The code I am using is below.  You can see where the for loop is commented out.

When I run this code with the for loop, there are no problems.  When I run it (in debug) using `parallel_for`, it crashes at random points with "Unhandled exception at 0x00f3d4ae in FratarProcess.exe 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000.

Note: `accessMatrix` is declared as `vector <vector <unsigned short> > accessMatrix;` and is filled prior to this point.

```
void dumpMatrix(unsigned short m)
{

int complete=0, start=2532, todo=accessMatrix.size()-start;

    vector <string> sqlStrings;

    Concurrency::parallel_for(start, (int)accessMatrix.size(),[&complete,&todo,&m,&sqlStrings](int i)
    //for(int i=start;i<accessMatrix.size();i++)
    {
        printf("Processing i=%i... completed %i/%i\n",i,complete,todo);
        for(unsigned short j=1;j<accessMatrix[i].size();j++)
        {
            if(accessMatrix[i][j]>0)
            {
                stringstream strSQL;
                strSQL << "INSERT INTO debug.dbf (I,J,M,V) VALUES(" << i << "," << j << "," << m << "," << accessMatrix[i][j] << ")";
                sqlStrings.push_back(strSQL.str());
            }
        }
        complete++;
    });
...
}
```

Can someone get me pointed in the right direction so I can get this process using all 8 cores of my machine instead of one?  Note that I am somewhat of a novice at C++.  I am using Visual C++ Express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used no synchronization protection for sqlStrings. It is not safe to mutate the container, print to output, or even increment a shared variable from multiple threads concurrently without using synchronization.

Comment: Okay, so after reading your answer and doing some more research, it looks like I should be declaring sqlStrings as `Concurrency::concurrent_vector <string> sqlStrings;`, and it works on running one test.  So far, so good.  Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

This will also solve the problem:

Declare a `combinable` object:

`Concurrency::combinable<vector <string>> sqlStringsCombinable;`

And in the loop:

`sqlStringsCombinable.local().push_back(strSQL.str());`

After the loop, combine them:

```
sqlStringsCombinable.combine_each([&sqlStrings](const std::vector<CString>& vec)
    {
        std::copy(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), back_inserter(sqlStrings));
    });
```

And this will speed up `parallel_for` as opposed to manually synchronizing the loop.

Comment: I already marked the answer above, but yours appears to be correct also and I really appreciate you posting it.  I would up-vote it if I had the 15 reputation SO requires for me to do so.  Again, thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Concurrent_Vector class.

1. Add `#include<concurrent_vector.h>`.
2. then add `using namespace concurrency;`.
3. Then you can initialize the vector like so `concurrent_vector<pair<int,int>> xy_coords;`.

The usage of this vector is just like {std::vector} class.